# Radon Nikodym problem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let ($\Re$, B($\Re$), $\lambda$)  be the lebesgue measure space. Find a nonnegative finite valued borel measurable function g such that the measure $\mu$ defined as in the radon nikodym theorem is not sigma finite.

The hint says that i should think about indicator functions, but i cant find the function.

Comment: you mean something like $\mu (E)=\int_{E}g\,\mathrm d \lambda $? If $g$ is finite valued then it is necessarily a simple function, otherwise $g\notin L^1(\lambda )$.

Comment: @Masacroso I am pretty sure that by finite valued OP  means $\mathbb  R$ valued. Further why do you think $g$ should be intergable?

Comment: @Kabo Murphy AFAIK the Radon-Nikodym theorem says that if $\mu $ is a $\sigma $-finite measure $\nu $ is a complex measure and $\nu \ll \mu $ then exists a unique $g\in L^1(\mu )$ such that $\nu (E)=\int_{E}g\,\mathrm d \mu $

Comment: @Masacroso OP is looking for non-sigma finite $\mu$. $g \in L^{1}$ would make $\mu$ finite. The version of RNT you are quoting is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @Kabo I dont know what the Op is asking because the question is not clear, and you neither

Comment: @Masacroso The question is the  following: find a Lebesgue  measurable function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu (E)=\int_E g d\lambda$ is not sigma finite.

Comment: @Kabo: Such a function does not exist. Think about decomposing $\Bbb{R}$ as $\bigcup \{x : x \in [-n,n] \text{ and } |g(x)| \leq n\}$.

Comment: @PhoemueX You are right. Why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @PhoemueX That is what I thought but I dont think the question is wrong, there has to be a function that satisfies that